# Generate a random string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, random

I'm trying to get a random string in phpmyadmin using a function. 
I have the following code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION randomPassword()
RETURNS varchar(128)
BEGIN

    SET @chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    SET @charLen = length(@chars);

    SET @randomPassword = '';

    WHILE length(@randomPassword) < 12
        SET @randomPassword = concat(@randomPassword, substring(@chars,CEILING(RAND() * @charLen),1));
    END WHILE;

    RETURN @randomPassword ;
END;
```

Now I get the error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: That specific message typically refers to missing parentheses, so that would be my guess.

Comment: END WHILE is wrong. You need only END at the end of a WHILE loop

Comment: It's my first function writing for mysql, so i have no idea what parentheses i'm missing?

Comment: If I was doing my first function, I'd start with something simpler!!

Comment: According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/while.html , mysql uses END WHILE

Comment: i did write functions in oracle pl/sql before just not in mysql

Comment: Most easy way to generate a random password in mysql would be `SELECT SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 12) AS password ;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's solved by using the Delimiter, i don't know for sure how, but it works
Thanks

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION randomPassword()
RETURNS varchar(128)
BEGIN

SET @chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
SET @charLen = length(@chars);

SET @randomPassword = '';

WHILE length(@randomPassword) < 12
    DO
    SET @randomPassword = concat(@randomPassword, substring(@chars,CEILING(RAND() * @charLen),1));
END WHILE;

RETURN @randomPassword ;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 26):

This is faster than `concat` + `substring` routine.

```sql
select substring(MD5(RAND()),1,20);
```

As I've tested inserting 1M random data, `md5` routine consumes only **1/4** (even less) time of `concat` + `substring` routine;

The problem is a md5 string contains only 32 chars so if you need a longer one you'd have to manually generate more md5 strings and `substring` it yourself.

Answer (score 10):

Try this more simple solution:

```
SELECT CONV(FLOOR(RAND() * 99999999999999), 10, 36)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE( TO_BASE64(MD5(RAND())), '=',''),'+',''),'/',''), 2, 40)
```

This solution to generate a fixed length random string that contains all lower- and upper-case chars and digits.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE( TO_BASE64(MD5(RAND())), '=',''),'+',''),'/',''), 2, FLOOR(10+RAND()*31))
```

If you need a random length string (from 10 to 40 symbols in this example)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION randomPassword()
RETURNS varchar(128)
AS
BEGIN

declare @chars nvarchar(25);
declare @charlen int;
declare @randomPassword nvarchar(128);

SET @chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
SET @charLen = len(@chars);

SET @randomPassword = '';

WHILE(LEN(@randomPassword) < 12)
BEGIN
    SET @randomPassword = concat(@randomPassword, substring(@chars,CEILING(RAND() * @charLen),1));
END

RETURN @randomPassword
END
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS
BEGIN

declare @chars nvarchar(25)' at line 3

Comment: Try to remove ..AS.. Maybe in MySql it works in this way

Comment: already did: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@chars nvarchar(25)' at line 5

Comment: substitute NVARCHAR to VARCHAR

Comment: oh yeah, should have seen that. but still gives the same error though